# the title does not appear in “ClassicThesis style”

Tags: titles, classicthesis

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\title\{APPUNTI FISICA \\ A.A. 2014/2015} 
\author{Gianni Rossi}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}

\strictpagecheck

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
{\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
{{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter%
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}  }{10pt}%
{\spacedallcaps}[\chapterdecoration]

\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\newcommand\anglei{-45}
\newcommand\angleii{45}
\newcommand\angleiii{225}
\newcommand\angleiv{135}

\newcommand\chapterdecoration{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]
    \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
    \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
    \coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
    \coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
    \else
    \coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=4.5cm]current page.north west);
    \coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north west);
    \renewcommand\anglei{-135}
    \renewcommand\angleii{135}
    \renewcommand\angleiii{-45}
    \renewcommand\angleiv{45}
    \fi
    \begin{scope}[halfgray!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
    \draw
    (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
    ++(\angleiii:5) --
    ++(\anglei:5.1) coordinate (b);
    \draw[shorten <= -10pt]
    (aux3) --
    (a) --
    (aux1);
    \draw[opacity=0.6,halfgray,shorten <= -10pt]
    (b) --
    ++(\angleiii:2.2) --
    ++(\anglei:2.2);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[halfgray,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
    (aux4) --
    ++(\angleiii:0.8) --
    ++(\anglei:0.8);
    \begin{scope}[halfgray!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
    \draw[shorten <= -10pt]
    (aux2) --
    ++(\angleiii:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
    ++(\anglei:3.1);
    \draw
    (aux2) --
    (c) --
    ++(\angleiv:2.5) --
    ++(\angleii:2.5) --
    ++(\anglei:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
    \draw 
    (d) -- +(\angleii:1);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

    \mbox{}\newpage%just for the example
    \chapter{meccanica}
    \section{preambolo}
    In fisica si trattano le grandezze misurabili, non opinionabili, espresse in numeri. Sfrutta la matematica per definire grandezze rispetto a misure. Si definiscono le cose con misure. {\raggedleft\textsc{le grandezze della fisica si definiscono con il procedimento con il quale le si misura. tale metodo deve essere riproducibile.}}L'unità di misura deve essere quindi riproducibile. Deve essere quindi uguale per tutti.\\Le grandezze della meccanica sono: {\raggedleft\textsc{lunghezza, tempo, massa.}} Con queste tre si è in grado di ricavare tutte le altre.
    \begin{description}
    \item[standard di massa] Cilindro da 1 Kg
    \item[standard di lunghezza] 1 m
    \item[standard di tempo] 1 s
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```

the problem is that when I run, do not show me the title but a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
   \mbox{}\newpage%just for the example
```

generates an empty page. Replace it with

```
\maketitle
```

to get a title page containing your `\title`, `\author` and such in the scrbook-style.

And your title has an `\` in the beginning too much it should read

```
\title{APPUNTI FISICA \\ A.A. 2014/2015}
```

(instead of `\title\{APPUNTI FISICA \\ A.A. 2014/2015}`)